# How to extract from YFinance API information for multiple companies

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I need to extract from yFinance API the governance score for the following companies: microsoft (MSFT), apple (AAPL) and visa (V).

i wrote this code that actually works fine, but what about a for cicle to quickly build up a database?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
msft.sustainability.iloc[11]
aapl.sustainability.iloc[11]
v.sustainability.iloc[11]
```

The following code is something I wrote that doesn't work... can someone help e fixing it? It keeps on giving me this error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sustainability'

```
my_list = []
ticker = ['msft', 'aapl', 'v']
for company in ticker:
    company.sustainability.iloc[11]
    my_list.append(governance)
```

Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: That first code snippet is incomplete, no? _This is something that doesn't work... can someone help e fixing it?_ Can you be more specific? What is the issue?

Comment: Fixed it, i did specify the error!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
my_list = []
ticker = [msft(), aapl(), v()]
for company in ticker:
    company.sustainability.iloc[11]
    my_list.append(governance)
```

You are trying to use a string to call the other variables in that class and python wont accept that. Use it as a class (which im assuming it is)

Comment: mmh it's still giving me an error (TypeError: 'Ticker' object is not callable), do you have any idea why?